# IMCE Image upload button does not show in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, imce-file-browser

I install IMCE and CKEditor modules in drupal 7. 
 But, it does not show image upload button. I already set the setting.

[image]

But, I create virtual host and the browser shows "**Connection is not secure**" alert. So, button does not show problem deals with this alert? 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Had the similar situation recently and used IMCE many times before without any issues. Something is wrong there...

Comment: Yes. I try to find the solution for the whole day. Now, I give up. :(

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to try using some older version of module...

Comment: Yes. @MilanG. Thanks . Btw, can I ask you something please? I add <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_path().path_to_theme() ?>/images/provider-1.jpg" />  in php format editor. Then I save. When I open again, img class name remove automatically. I use CKeditor. How can I solve this ?

Comment: At back-end go to Configuration -> Content authoring -> Text formats. There you have defined different text formats, like "Full html", "Filtered HTML"... Edit the one you are using. They can be selected directly bellow WYSIWYG editor at page where editor is used. At bottom of the edit page you'll see what filters do they use. Those filters are modifying edited markup, so remove one that destroys you attributes.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG. I will try your suggestion. Btw, which module do you use for thumbnail images slider usually in drupal 7 ?

Comment: I'm using image styles for generating image thumbnails, but not using any drupal module for slider. I'm getting working static HTML templates and just replace static image paths and stuff with ones I'm reading from node fields...

Comment: yes bro. @MilanG. could you please take a look at my another problem https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242250/submenu-does-not-show-in-theme-drupal-7  ?

Answer (score 0):

please try below steps :

1. Goto /admin/config/media/imce and assign profile for particular role.
2. Then edit that profile (EX: admin/config/media/imce/profile/edit/1) and enable Directories permission.

Thanks,
Ankush

Comment: thanks bro. But, it does not work. Still not appear the button. btw, could you please check my another problem  bro https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242250/submenu-does-not-show-in-theme-drupal-7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with IMCE when using a Bootstrap Subtheme. I needed to remove a function from template.php (that wasn't needed anyways) to make IMCE work again. Hope that helps!